# Partitions of sets, Bell number, and equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

https://gateoverflow.in/54949/how-many-equivalence-classes-can-be-made-form-1-2-3
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

On the wiki page under the section for set partitions it says that for a set {a,b,c} there are 5 set partitions, and in the top link it says that there are 5 equivalence relations, how are these related?

Comment: "*How are these related?*"  For every equivalence relation there is a corresponding partition and vice versa.  There are exactly as many partitions as there are equivalence relations for a set.

Comment: Where could I read about this in more detail?